# Are there any freely available dictionaries?

Tags: database, dictionary, cpu-word

I want to create dictionary for my iPhone application. For that I need a list of words with detailed meanings of the words in a database.

Can anyone suggest me a good word list that is freely available?

Comment: You should also have it do spell-check...

Comment: hmm… download a dump of wiktionary?

Comment: yes if you have idea from where I can download dump please send me link

Comment: @webdestroya Well, you have enough reputation to fix up the post.

Answer (score 3):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is indeed great,  I used it in one of my apps with nice results.

WordNet's API requires some adaptation though - it doesn't come with an API for Objective-C, for example. That's why I made [Lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com/) available as a static library - you might want to check it out too.

Answer (score 2):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) would be a fantastic place to start.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.wikipedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/

May be a good place to look.